# Filter DataTable rows based on a column value in C#2.0

Tags: .net, datatable, c#-2.0

I have a datable with n number of rows/columns. I would like to filter the rows based on a column which has only one character value as "*". My version is C#2.0. How to filter the rows and copy into a new datatable.

This code is not working;

```
DataTable result = dt.Select("FLAG= '*'");
```

Comment: the filter criteria is column with only value as "*" in the cell

Comment: Can't reproduce that actually https://dotnetfiddle.net/SwIvlk

Comment: Updated the code in https://dotnetfiddle.net/SwIvlk it throws error now

Comment: i don’t see your changes, you must press share button to apply them.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1L1iZA Please find the updated code here

Answer (score 0):

I got this worked by applying these steps. CopyToTable doesn't work in C#2.0.

Created an array of datarows by filtering it based on criteria.

```
string expression;
expression = "FLAG= '*' ";
DataRow[] filteredRows;
```

// Use the Select method to find all rows matching the filter.

```
filteredRows= dt.Select(expression);
```

Then, create a new datatable out of the datarows

```
 foreach (DataRow drow in filteredRows)
                {

                    dtnew.ImportRow(drow);
                }
```